# cannot import name 'AllennlpDataset' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_reader'

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, chatbot, opennlp, allennlp

I am trying to implement one research paper. While running this code (https://github.com/abubakar-ucr/LEONA/blob/master/model/end2end_model.py), I keept getting this error. The error occurs at line number 36.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "end2end_model.py", line 36, in <module>
    from allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_reader import AllennlpDataset
ImportError: cannot import name 'AllennlpDataset' from 'allennlp.data.dataset_readers.dataset_reader'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @IvanShelonik I have attached the code link in the description. Please have a look.

Comment: Believe nobody cannot surely say why some modules cannot be imported working with 3rd party open source library. But as I understand properly, you need to install "allennpl" library with all plugins and as we see something is not installed correctly. Ask the question right into "allennpl" https://github.com/allenai/allennlp and get proper guidence. It can also be possible that Module names changed

Comment: You may have to install an older version of AllenNLP for that to work. The AllennlpDataset class was removed a while ago.